# Importing proto files and compiling

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have two proto files in the following directories -

```
parsers/
   > flights/
       > flights_proto/
           > flights.proto
           > flights.pb.go
   > flightspostbooking
       > flights_postbooking_proto/
           > flights_postbooking.proto
           > flights_postbooking.pb.go
```

Following are the contents of the proto files -

```
flights.proto
=============

package "flights_proto";

message Flight {
   ...
}

flights_postbooking.proto
=========================

package "flights_postbooking_proto"
import "flights_proto/flights.proto"

message Cancel {
    Flight flight = 1;
    ...
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to compile the `flights_postbooking.proto` to generate the `pb.go` file.

I tried to do the following from the `parsers` directory.

```
protoc --proto_path=flightspostbooking/flights_postbooking_proto --proto_path=flights/flights_proto flightspostbooking/flights_postbooking_proto/flights_postbooking.proto --go_out=plugins:flights_postbooking_proto
```

But I get an error that `flights_proto/flights.proto: File not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `protoc` from the `parsers` directory, and use the base directory for your proto files, which is `.`

```
protoc --proto_path=. --go_out=plugins=grpc:flightpostbooking/flights_postbooking_proto flightpostbooking/flights_postbooking_proto/flights_postbooking.proto
```

Since you have the `parsers` directory as your base, your import should be:

```
import "flights/flights_proto/flights.proto"
```

The key is to use import paths relative to your `proto_path`.